# mysql SELECT query syntax issue

Tags: mysql, sql, operand

```
SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE que_id =(select * from emp_qusans where emp_id=9 and ans!=3)
```

The query throws the following error message.

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the `emp_qusans` table, an exact answer cannot be given.

Comment: OK check this link for table structure. https://ibb.co/kOOpL5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the table structure you shared with us, you probably intend to select the `qid` column in your subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE que_id = (SELECT qid FROM emp_qusans WHERE emp_id = 9 AND ans != 3)
```

By the way, the operand error you were getting was happening because `SELECT *` returns *multiple* columns (read: values), but you were trying to compare this to a single scalar column.  Obviously, that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your sub query returns one row and you need to use column name instead of * in your sub query.

```
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE que_id = (select [column name] 
                from emp_qusans 
                where emp_id=9 and ans!=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of * you should provide column name.

SELECT * FROM question WHERE que_id =(select **[column_name]** from emp_qusans where emp_id=9 and ans!=3)

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your query

> use in clause instead of =
>   your sub query returns full table emp_qusans, please specify a column from this table.

Your query would be like this

SELECT * FROM `question` WHERE que_id in (select eq.column1 from emp_qusans eq where eq.emp_id=9 and eq.ans!=3)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM question WHERE que_id =(select [column_name] from emp_qusans where emp_id=9 and ans!=3)